# error in netbeans about join method

Tags: java, collections

```
   ArrayList<T> set=new ArrayList<T>();


   for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
       {
       for(int j=0;j<t.size();j++)
       {
           if(!list.get(i).equals(t.get(i)));------------>netbeans say t.get(i) is error
               set.add((T) t.list.get(j));
       }
```

i should write a join method to join two set.What should I write instead of t.get(i)????

Comment: sorry it must be t.get(j) not t.get(i)

Comment: You definitely should write more clear question.

Comment: "ArrayList set=..." - this one is hilarious. :D

Comment: why hilarious?where will I put my set after joining?

Comment: Ahhh, so that what's going on! It's hilarious since list is not a set and set is not a list. They're two distinct data structures with it's own semantics. Lists can have one item many times in it. Sets only have unique elements. Also, lists can be randomly accessed (by index) while sets cannot. That said, all you need to do is to use a set with it's addAll() method. It's got the same semantics as your code listing.

Answer (score 2):

And what about `list.size()`? Both `list` and `t` are undefined (at least in the code snippet you have sent).

Please try to read what does compiler say you. I believe that error message will explain you where the problem is. If you still do not understand please supply bigger code snippet.

Comment: I agree. I don't see them declared anywhere in the code as well

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work on a set data structure, start using a set.

```
Set set = new HashSet();
```

The semantics of a "Set" already imply that there are no duplicates in it. To have a union, simply add all new elements.